# Forward Declaration of enum in C++ giving scope error?

Tags: c++, enums, forward-declaration

I am following along in a tutorial on C++ and we've arrived to the topic of enumerated types. [Here is a link to the exact lesson in the website if anyone is curious](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/45-enumerated-types/)

They state that you can forward declare an enum if you specify the int type being used, so I attempted something like this:

```
enum Item : short;
 
int main()
{
    Item item { ITEM_SWORD };
    std::cout << "Item: " << item << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
 
enum Item : short
{
    ITEM_SWORD,
    ITEM_SHEILD,
    ITEM_TORCH,
};
```

But this produced an error: 'ITEM_SWORD' was not declared in this scope. I read some of the responses to other questions on the same issue and one response from one of the admins of the tutorial read something like this "You can't use enumerators before the enum is defined. The forward declaration only allows you to declare enum variables (eg. as parameters in a forward declaration of a function)." Can someone please explain this clearly? I altered my code because of the way I interpreted his response to something like this:

```
enum Item : short;
void printItem(Item item);
 
int main()
{
    Item item { ITEM_SWORD };
    std::cout << "Item: " << printItem(item) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
 
enum Item : short
{
    ITEM_SWORD,
    ITEM_SHEILD,
    ITEM_TORCH,
};
 
void printItem(Item item)
{
    if (item == ITEM_SWORD)
    {
        std::cout << "Sword\n";
    }
    if (item == ITEM_SHEILD)
    {
        std::cout << "Sheild\n";
    }
    if (item == ITEM_TORCH)
    {
        std::cout << "Torch\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "???\n";
    }
}
```

But this only lead to a whole slew of other errors and warnings that aren't clear at all. Can someone please explain what the tutorial admin meant in his response?? A concrete example would greatly be appreciated, maybe even a few. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you forward-declared the name `Item`, but not the name `ITEM_SWORD`. At the point where the compiler sees `ITEM_SWORD` for the first time, it has no idea what it means; hence the error. You can't forward-declare enum values, only the enum type itself (e.g. so you can use it in a function declaration, like `printItem` in your example).

Comment: In your second code sample, having `void printItem(Item item);` before the definition of `Item` is fine. It just relies on the fact that at some point, you'll have something called an `Item`. But `Item item { ITEM_SWORD };` isn't fine, because at the time that call is processed, you haven't declared `ITEM_SWORD` yet, you've just forward-declared `Item`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for the quick response. But i'm afraid I still don't fully understand. Sorry, I'm normally pretty quick to grasp concepts but this one just doesn't make sense to me. I think they're might just be a disconnect between my understanding of what an enumerated type really is and the enumerators within the enumeration definition. Could you please give a concrete example, along the lines of what I posted? Thanks again!

Comment: Concrete example of what - of forward-declaring an enum value? I can't - it's not possible. Concrete example of forward-declaring enum type? You have it: `enum Item : short; void printItem(Item item);`  (Note how `Item` is used before it's defined).

Comment: In C++, every name must be introduced by a declaration (or definition; a definition is also a declaration) before it can be used in any way (with the sole exception of `goto` label names, if I recall correctly). A declaration tells the compiler what the name means (e.g. whether it names a type, or a variable, or a function, or something else). Your example attempts to use the name `ITEM_SWORD` before it has been declared.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I understand that al variables and functions need to be declared before they can be used. So is `enum Item : int` not considered a declaration? I guess this is where the disconnect is happening; I don't think I fully grasp what an enum is. I view enums as just sort of "containers" for related symbolic constants. So when I forward declare in this way `enum Item : int` that isn't really telling the compiler of the existence of the contents inside Item also? I think a really concrete, rigorous definition of what an enum is would help.

Comment: `enum Item : int` is in fact a declaration - it says that `Item` is a name of an enum type, and that `sizeof(Item) == sizeof(int)`. Now you can use the name `Item` anywhere this information is sufficient. But that doesn't say anything about the meaning of a different name, `ITEM_SWORD`. It is the use of `ITEM_SWORD` that triggers the error, not the use of `Item`. Lacking a time machine or a crystal ball, the compiler cannot determine that `ITEM_SWORD` will eventually, at some later point, be defined as a enum value of the enum type `Item`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ahh okay so I think I'm slowly getting it. So in other words, there is no (reasonable, non-convoluted) way of doing what I'm trying to do? That is, define the enum after main( )? That is, of course, if I'm reading all this correctly. Because in your first comment you said we can't forward declare enum values themselves, only the type. So the only (again reasonable, non-convoluted) way of telling the compiler of the existence of the enumerators inside the enum is to define the enum above main( )?

Comment: Why do you want to do that - define the enum after the function that uses it? What's the ultimate goal of this exercise?

Comment: Mainly for consistency. We can define functions after main( ) and then tell the compiler of their existence via a forward declaration, and I haven't gotten to class definitions yet, but i imagine the same is possible for them, so I thought it was reasonable that the same could be done for enums. I understand that not to be the case now.

Comment: To be completely honest, I dont understand the point of forward declaring an enum now. So far the only reason to forward declare has been to tell the compiler of the existence of a variable/function before evaluating main( ) (i.e. when we define a function after main, or when we use an external global variable), but if we just define enums before main( ) anyways, why the forward declaration at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222872/discussion-between-oni-barolli-and-igor-tandetnik).